# $\forall p \ge 11 \quad \exists n \in \{1,2,\dots,9\}$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ are quadratic residues mod p

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I must solve the following problem:

> $\forall p \ge 11 \quad \exists n \in \{1,2,\dots,9\}$ such that $n$ and $n+1$ are quadratic residues mod $p$.

I read some questions here about this topic but I found them a bit different so I couldn't find my answer.

My attempt is the following:

- we know that a prime $p$ is $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4 $ or $p \equiv -1 \pmod 4 $, so I divided the two cases
- CASE 1: $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4  \longrightarrow (2|p)=1 $ and $(1|p)=1 \forall p$
- CASE 2: $p \equiv -1 \pmod 4$. It is sufficient to control the primes $q \in \{1,2,\dots,9\}$ because $(a|p)=1$ and $(b|p)=1 \longrightarrow (ab|p)=1$. So I must check $q=\{2,3,5,7\}$.

From here I am not able to continue.
Have you any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: one of $2,5,10$ must be a quadratic residue.

Comment: @Phi_24 Since $(10 | p)=(2|p)(5 |p)$, then $\{1,2\}$ or $\{4,5\}$ or $\{9,10\}$ will work, i.e if $2$ is a QR then $\{1,2\}$ will satisfy your condition. If both $2$ and $5$ are QNR, then $10$ will be a QR, hence $\{9,10\}$ will satisfy the conditions.

Comment: @Anurag A Ah, you're right! Thank you.